# SQL Group By clause.. change the new column name

Tags: sql, db2, mysql-workbench

There are three columns in a table namely, `Student name`, `Subject name` & `Marks`.
There are three subjects `Physics`, `Chemistry` & `Maths`.. there are marks mentioned in front of them.

Then In this case If we want to run `Group By Statement` with Function `AVG`. then in the result a new column is created by default.

If I want to change the Column `name` of the new One.. How can I change?

Comment: `AVG(column)as yourname`

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use alias. so use below

```
select avg(marks) as YourColumnName from ...
```